# Why does blender shutdown while trying to delete vertices?

Tags: error

So I'm trying to print the head of the Leviathan axe from God of War 4. The model I received is a highly detailed model with stock, handle, and wrappings. I'm trying to delete everything but the axe head, but no matter how low of vertices, even just one, while I select ... Blender closes when I try to delete it. What is wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Are there any error that jump out at you when it shutdown or it's just goes blank? It could be your system being short in memory or your graphic card ran out of vram as the model is highly detailed? If it's highly detail can you describe how many polygon and vertices your model has? If deleting vertices is an issue have you tried selecting faces and delete the faces first? It's also useful to note that selection made in small batch will help slower system to cope with ram issue.

Comment: It just closes, no error screen. No matter what I pick to delete it closes, even if it's just one. I understand it that it's mostly likely because of how detailed it is. Is there anyway to lower it to where I can work with it without problems?

Comment: Edit mode > select a vertex on the axe head you want > hit L > hit P and separate the mesh to a different object. If not setup a google drive file so I could see what's happening there... it could be file corruption as well.